# matlab function to python function conversion

Tags: python, matlab, function

I have a matlab function

```
function [indx, indy] = coord2index(hres, vres, hdiv, vdiv, x, y)

  indx = hdiv + x + 1;

  indy = -1*y + vdiv;
```

How can I convert it to python function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can be wrong but have you tried this:

```
def coord2index(hres, vres, hdiv, vdiv, x, y):
    return hdiv + x + 1, (-1) * y + vdiv
```

You can read more on [functions defining in python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be something like this:

```
def coord2index(hres, vres, hdiv, vdiv, x, y):
  indx = hdiv + x + 1
  indy = -1*y + vdiv
  return indx, indy
```

Assuming your inputs are `numpy.ndarray` the shape broadcasting should work the same as matlab.